# Ubuntu 20 efi "can't find command 'hwmatch' " on boot

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I've got clean install Ubuntu 20 on my dell 5593 and to start things of:
I made efi, home and root partition and it all installed without problems untill the reboot.
The error i got was:

```
error: can't find command 'hwmatch'.
error: Command failed. (this repeats several times)
error: you need to load the kernel first.
Press any key to continue...
Failed to boot both default and fallback entries
Press any key to continue...
```

After that i get the usual grub menu, but whatever entry i choose i got

```
error: Command failed. (this repeats several times)
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

So i reinstalled using the automatic partition option and this time i didn't get this error for 2 days. But today I encountered this problem again. I tried upgrading && updating, but no luck.

One thing that allows me to boot is simply hitting ESC after the error messages and writing "exit" in grub command line. The booting sequence refreshes and ubuntu boots without errors. Any Ideas how to fix that?